# How to know if an App is in the recent app list or not?

Tags: android

I was building a feature on my app where I need to check if the app is in the recent app list or not. If it is in the recent app list I will start some service and if it is not in the recent app list I will wait for the app's next time run. But I didnt find any way about how to detect if this app is in the recent app list or not? So far I have learned is in a service `onTaskRemoved` can help, but in android 9 this service will also get killed to preserve memory. Can anyone give me a suggestion how can I get that?

Comment: "If it is in the recent app list I will start some service and if it is not in the recent app list I will wait for the app's next time run" -- why?

Comment: @CommonsWare it's a client requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check getRecentTasks() method from Activity manager [ActivitManager docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRecentTasks(int,%20int))  to get recent tasks. note >> it works just till api 21

Comment: you can add time stamp for  last use then on next time user open app check since when was last use  if it short period  your  action